# Is there a way to convert a variadic function into one that receives an array and vice versa in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, variadic-functions

**Code I'm trying:**

```
fileprivate func concatPairs(_ pairStrings: [String]) -> String {
    return "{\n" + pairStrings.joined(separator: ",\n") + "}\n"
}

fileprivate func concatPairs(_ pairStrings: String...) -> String {
    return concatPairs(pairStrings)
}

let p1 = jsonify(pair: ("size", 15), quoteValue: false)
let p2 = jsonify(pair: ("length", 23.12), quoteValue: false)
concatPairs(p1, p2)
concatPairs([p1, p2])
```

Is there a way to convert a `variadic function` into one that receives an array and vice versa? I would like to avoid all the extra typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Any` as argument type.

```
fileprivate func concatPairs(_ pairStrings: Any...) -> String {
    if let strings = pairStrings as? [[String]] {
        let newStrings = strings.flatMap { $0 }
        return "{\n" + newStrings.joined(separator: ",\n") + "}\n"
    }
    else if let _ = pairStrings.first as? String {
        return concatPairs(pairStrings)
    }
    return ""    
}
```

Comment: Nice hack, but if you pass two or more arrays the result will be surprising. So the language doesn't have good support for this kind of things, it seems.

Comment: @qed That was right, But your requirements is not that, you want solution for your two function that you have added in question, and none of that include two argument as array of string.

Comment: I know, just the signature suggests it can take multiple arrays, a bit misleading. For my use case it should be fine, since I am aware of this quirk.

Comment: @qed Lat's wait for some other answer may be that will full fill your requirements.

Comment: @qed I'have edited answer now it will also work if you pass multiple array of String as arguments.

Comment: Cool. I think the `else if let strings = pairStrings.first as? [String] ` part is not necessary.

Comment: @qed Yes, You are right, I missed it, edited answer for that.